# Quaternions and drawing with glMultMatrix (OpenGL)

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, quaternions

I got a problem again. Since a couple of days I try to write a camera in Java without a gimbal lock. For solving this I try to use Quaternions and glMultMatrix from OpenGL. I also use the library "LWJGL" especially the classes [Matrix4f](http://lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/util/vector/Matrix4f.html), [Vector4f](http://lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/util/vector/Vector4f.html) and Quaternions.
Here is the code which calculates the Quaternions:

```
        int DX = Mouse.getDX(); //delta-mouse-movement
        int DY = Mouse.getDY();

        Vector4f axisY = new Vector4f();
            axisY.set(0, 1, 0,DY);
        Vector4f axisX = new Vector4f();
            axisX.set(1, 0, 0, DX);

        Quaternion q1 = new Quaternion();
            q1.setFromAxisAngle(axisX);
        Quaternion q2 = new Quaternion();
            q2.setFromAxisAngle(axisY);

        Quaternion.mul(q1, q2, q1);
        Quaternion.mul(camera,q1,camera);
```

And whit this I convert the Quaternion into a matrix:

```
public Matrix4f quatToMatrix(Quaternion q){
    double sqw = q.w*q.w;
    double sqx = q.x*q.x;
    double sqy = q.y*q.y;
    double sqz = q.z*q.z;

    Matrix4f m = new Matrix4f();
    // invs (inverse square length) is only required if quaternion is not already normalised
    double invs = 1 / (sqx + sqy + sqz + sqw);
    m.m00 = (float)(( sqx - sqy - sqz + sqw)*invs) ; // since sqw + sqx + sqy + sqz =1/invs*invs
    m.m11 = (float)((-sqx + sqy - sqz + sqw)*invs);
    m.m22 =(float) ((-sqx - sqy + sqz + sqw)*invs);

    double tmp1 = q.x*q.y;
    double tmp2 = q.z*q.w;
    m.m10 = (float) (2.0 * (tmp1 + tmp2)*invs);
    m.m01 = (float) (2.0 * (tmp1 - tmp2)*invs) ;

    tmp1 = q.x*q.z;
    tmp2 = q.y*q.w;
    m.m20 = (float)(2.0 * (tmp1 - tmp2)*invs) ;
    m.m02 = (float)(2.0 * (tmp1 + tmp2)*invs) ;
    tmp1 = q.y*q.z;
    tmp2 = q.x*q.w;
    m.m21 = (float)(2.0 * (tmp1 + tmp2)*invs) ;
    m.m12 = (float)(2.0 * (tmp1 - tmp2)*invs) ;      

    return m;
}
```

A converted Quaternion looks for example like this:

```
-0.5191307 0.027321965 -0.85425806 0.0
0.048408303 -0.9969446 -0.061303165 0.0
-0.8533229 -0.07317754 0.51622194 0.0
0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0
```

After this I draw the scene with this code:

```
    java.nio.FloatBuffer fb = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(32);
    quatToMatrix(camera).store(fb);
    GL11.glMultMatrix(fb);

    drawPlayer();
```

My problem now is that the camera maybe doesn't move, or doesn't move enough, because I only see my player model and nothing else (There also is another cube in the scene I draw after the player model).

I don't know what exactly is wrong. Is it the drawing, the rotation, or the converting?
Please help me.

EDIT:

that is my OpenGL initialisation:

```
GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
GL11.glLoadIdentity(); 
GLU.gluPerspective(45.0f, ((float) setting.displayW() / (float) setting.displayH()), 0.1f,10000.0f); 
GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW); 
GL11.glLoadIdentity(); 
GL11.glShadeModel(GL11.GL_SMOOTH); 
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST); 
GL11.glDepthFunc(GL11.GL_LEQUAL);
GL11.glHint(GL11.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL11.GL_NICEST);
```

Any Idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you've got some errors in your mouse movement to quaternion function (where do you make a quaternion of the X movement?). Besides that, we'd also need to see the rest of your drawing setup code (projection matrix, modelview initialization).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! that is my opengl initialisation:         GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
  GL11.glLoadIdentity();
  GLU.gluPerspective(45.0f, ((float) setting.displayW() / (float) setting.displayH()), 0.1f, 10000.0f);
  GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
  GL11.glLoadIdentity();
  GL11.glShadeModel(GL11.GL_SMOOTH); 
  GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
  GL11.glDepthFunc(GL11.GL_LEQUAL); 
  GL11.glHint(GL11.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT,   GL11.GL_NICEST); - what exactly do you mean with quaternion of X-movement? Do you mean this: axisX.set(1, 0, 0, DY); ?

Comment: mmh... I know^^ i got no idea how to post it more readable. Any idea how to solve my problem?

Comment: @mick: You can always edit your original question, making additions. And I meant that q2 = setFromAxisAngle(axisY). Either q1 or q2 should be created from axisX.

Comment: Oh, thank you! I fixed that, but it unfortunately it didn't fix my problem. I added the opengl init in my fist post. Is my rotation calculation etc correct now? I added the new result of the quatToMatrix, too.

Comment: @mick: I must admit, I'm not so familiar with the Java libraries supporting OpenGL, in that case the matrix clas. It could be, that you fell for common misconception and accidently transposed your matrix. OpenGL is column major, so it goes first down, then right on matrices. If Matrix4f doesn't already account for this, this could be a reason for the problem.

Comment: @datenwolf: So you think the problem is the drawing and not the calculation? The calculation took me a really long time.

Comment: @mick: No, I meant, that you maybe accidently transposed the matrices, which at least when accessing OpenGL using C is a common mistake made by newbies.

Comment: Ok, maybe that could be. Is it a side-effect that it draws nothing? I tought it would draw something even the transposing of the matrix is wrong. Thank you!

Comment: The matrix being transposed can easily shift your geometry off the NDC space coordinate range. So yes, it could prevent things from being drawn.

Comment: ok, thank you! I try to check this. It makes me happy that at least my calculation is correct^^

Comment: Does this really prevent gimbal lock? I just have seen this (http://code.google.com/p/3duis/source/browse/trunk/3DUiS/src/renderer/utilities/Camera.java?r=16) camera and tried to use it, but it suffers from gimbal lock and my rotation calculation is nearly the same. What do you say?